# Is there a directory of Wine compatible software?

Tags: wine

Is there a website that lists software that runs well, or not well, under Wine?

Comment: What are you trying to say? You want a Registry Editor?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, you can find compatibility reviews at the [Wine Application Database](http://appdb.winehq.org).

Not only can you find compatible software, you can submit your own apps and reviews to help others.