# Ubuntu compatibility with Wacom tablet CTH-461

Tags: 12.04, drivers, wacom, photoshop, bamboo

I just recently learned about the existence of Ubuntu, as I am considering purchasing a netbook with this Operating system installed. I have been reading up about it all week now, but as I'm not at all familiar with all technical terms, it's a bit much.

What I really wanted to know is if I can use my Wacom Bamboo CTH-461 with Ubuntu 12.04, and an easy explanation of how to install it, and if some script has to be run, or drivers downloaded, specifically how and where.

Also, I would be interested to know if Photoshop is installable (and if so, grade of difficulty).

Comment: I don't know how much this actually applies to the current version of Ubuntu, but you could take a look at [the community documentation for Photoshop](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AdobePhotoshop). According to that, it is a "massive pain to install.", but it looks like is duable.

Comment: Also take a look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/36585/wine-or-virtual-machine-virtualbox-to-run-apps-eg-photoshop) about running Photoshop.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to found out if it would work is to try the LiveCD, if it Launches, it will work.

Also see if everything works out of the box, if so, you don't need to configure anything.

As for Photoshop, if you install Wine and emulate windows, it should work, at least that's what people are saying in winehq database, but I suggest you to try Gimp, it's very similar to Photoshop (same layout as the old one form photoshop, before the CS versions came out) as it's native of linux.

Comment: Yes Ubuntu has drivers built in for most wacom devices, so there is a good chance your device will work out of the box. I have used many different wacom tablets and centique in the past in Ubuntu without problems.